# Sitio web con nginx apunta a donde no debe

Tags: nginx, vps

tengo un VPS corriendo en Ubuntu 20.04 con virtualmin y nginx.
Allí tengo alojados tres sitios.
El primero sitio1 corre una aplicación Next.js y los otros dos html plano.
Tanto el sitio1 y el sitio2 corren perfectamente, pero cuando ingreso al sitio3 aparece el sitio1.
Los archivos de configuración de conf.d de nginx son los siguientes:

Sitio1 (el que aparece cuando intento acceder al sitio3):

```
server {
    server_name sitio1.com.ar;
    location / {
        root /home/xxx/public_html/;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html{
            root /usr/share/ngninx/html;
    }
      

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio1.com.ar/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio1.com.ar/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }server {
        if ($host = sitio1.com.ar) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name sitio1.com.ar;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

El archivo .conf del sitio 2 es:

```
server {
    server_name sitio2.top;
    location / {
        root /home/xxx2/public_html/;
        
        
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html{
            root /usr/share/ngninx/html;
    }

}
```

Y por último el del sitio3:

```
server {
    server_name sitio3.top;
    location / {
        root /home/xxx3/public_html/;
        
        
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html{
            root /usr/share/ngninx/html;
    }

    }
```

Como ven la configuración del sitio2 y el 3 son iguales, sin embargo el sitio dos anda perfectamente, no asi el tres.
Si alguien puede ayudarme se los agradecerái mucho.